# Spring Data JPA Query with LIKE condition throws exception on runtime

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to make this simple JPA query working:

```
@Query("SELECT p FROM PersonImpl p WHERE p.customerReference LIKE :query ESCAPE '\\\\'")
public Page<Person> findByQuery(@Param("query") String query, Pageable pageable);
```

But upon application startup I get exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal like pattern :query!
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.StringQuery.getLikeTypeFrom(StringQuery.java:205)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.StringQuery.parseLikeBindings(StringQuery.java:155)
```

When I change the :query param into a string literal, for eg. 'foobar', then it's fine. Does  anyone know what's the issue here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently it was a [bug](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/DATAJPA-341) in Spring Data JPA 1.3.1. After upgrading to 1.3.4 it works as expected.